# Free Golang IDE

Tags: windows, linux, osx, ide, unix

Is there any good and free Golang IDE or Editor for MacOSX, Windows or Linux?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Free

- [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)   `MacOS, Windows, Linux`
- [Atom](https://atom.io/)                      `MacOS, Windows, Linux`
- [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)      `MacOS, Windows, Linux`

Answer (score 1):

[liteide](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide) lightweight multiplatform native ide